# Telegram Bot don't work by putting into server and use of webhook

Tags: c#, webhooks, telegram-bot

I create a bot from Bot-Father and also write a simple telegram bot in console application format of C#. My bot code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NetTelegramBotApi;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Requests;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Types;

namespace vinehTest
 {
  class Program
   {
    private static string token = " "; ---> a token from Bot-Father
    private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup mainMenue;
    private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup phoneMenue;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        mainMenue = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
        {
            Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][] {new KeyboardButton[] { new KeyboardButton("درباره ی ما"), new KeyboardButton("شماره تلفن ها ") },

                                                                      new KeyboardButton[] { new KeyboardButton("آخرین اخبار") }

                                              }
        };

        phoneMenue = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
        {
            Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][] { new KeyboardButton[] { new KeyboardButton("ریاست"), new KeyboardButton("بازاریاب "), new KeyboardButton("طراح") } ,
                                                new KeyboardButton[] { new KeyboardButton("بازگشت به منوی اصلی") }
                                               }
        };

        Task.Run(() => RunBot());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task RunBot()
    {

        var bot = new TelegramBot(token);
        var me = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetMe());
        Console.WriteLine(me.Username);
        long offset = 0;
        int whileCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While is {0}", whileCount);
            whileCount += 1;
            var updates = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });
            Console.WriteLine("update count is {0}", updates.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            try
            {
                foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    offset = update.UpdateId + 1;
                    var text = update.Message.Text;
                    if (text == "/start")
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "گزینه مورد نظر را وارد کنید") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.Contains("درباره ی ما"))
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "این شرکت در حوزه های تبلیغاتی فعال است") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.Contains("شماره تلفن ها"))
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "یکی ارز گزینه ها را انتخاب کنید") { ReplyMarkup = phoneMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.Contains("ریاست"))
                    { 
                        using(var stream = System.IO.File.Open("C://Users//sahar//Desktop//Pic//1.jpg",System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            var req = new SendPhoto(update.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend(stream,"1.jpg"));
                            await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.Contains("بازاریاب"))
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "لطفاً کمی صبر کنید") { ReplyMarkup = phoneMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open("C://Users//sahar//Desktop//video//2.mp4", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            var req2 = new SendVideo(update.Message.Chat.Id, new FileToSend(stream, "2.mp4"));
                            await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req2);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (text != null && text.Contains("بازگشت به منوی اصلی"))
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "امیدواریم توانسته باشیم شما را یاری کنیم") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "دستوری که فرستادید مفهوم نبود") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenue };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

when I run the code in visual studio 2012, My Bot work fine. But I need to put My bot in real server. So i put Newtonsoft.json.dll and NetTelegramBotApi.dll and myBot.exe from C# project in my server and use webhook to set token of my bot to host address and the result is:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

But my Bot don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out problem via following method:

Check [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) method, make sure your webhook URL is correct, and no `last_error_message` field.

POST similar data to your server, [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) is some data you can use in `curl -d JSON`, just copy it and run on your own server.

BTW, check your CDN config (if you had applied on that server), temporary disable flooding or any check.